# 2x2 ANOVA with non-normal distribution and Levene failure

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, assumptions, post-hoc, levenes-test

I am doing an MSc dissertation in psychology at the moment. I have collected data from 307 groups, and I am trying to run a 2x2 ANOVA.

The DV is 'number of conversations'. One IV has 2 levels (yes or no) and the other IV is group size (3 levels: 3-5, 6-7 & 8+).

The data has violated the assumptions of normality and homogeneity. My supervisor has said this doesn't actually matter; any real world data is likely to violate assumption of normality. The supervisor said I could carry on regardless.

However, they did say to bootstrap the post-hoc test for the main effect of group size in light of the violated Levene.

What do you think? In sum, the assumptions of normality and homogeneity are violated. Supervisor said it doesn't matter about normality, carry on and report the 2x2 ANOVA, but in post hoc tests do the bootstrap.

Any help or thoughts on the above is appreciated!!!

Comment: "Number of conversations" is a *count*. It's discrete and non-negative so it's *obviously* not normal. Why would you test what you already know?  Note further that you'd expect count data to be heteroskedastic. Why not consider models designed specifically for count data? Can you say more about the DV -- is it a variable that has a predefined upper bound, for example? Why has group size been categorized?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Your first question makes sense - and no, it does not have a predefined upper bound. Group size has been categorised because we are looking at the differences between groups of these size limits - i.e. the effects of IV 1 & 2 on the formation of conversations within groups. IV #1 is phone use (yes or no). Does that make sense? I understand that the normality may not matter because of the sample size. Supervisor says bootstrapping the post-hoc test (Tukey) will be sufficient to make up for Levene...

Comment: Does that make any more sense? Apparently I would just need to report as normal, but make sure at the start to say why I have bootstrapped the post-hoc testing. It's news to me but I'm still learning!

Comment: Your supervisor is somewhat mistaken, though it's not clear by how much (it may be a lot or it may only matter a little) -- the significance level may not be too far off as long as the conditional distribution isn't very skew, but you also want a test to have *good power* and that may be a problem (e.g. if the conditional distribution of the DV is heavy tailed it may matter quite a bit; simulation would be a way to get a sense of it). ... It's not clear to me why you'd bootstrap the post hoc but not the main test. If it was me I'd probably be looking at a Poisson or negative binomial model.